# Does realloc free the former buffer if it fails?

Tags: realloc

If realloc fails and returns NULL is the former buffer free'd or it is kept intact? I didn't found that particular piece of information in the man page and I'm quite unsure what to do. If memory is freed then double-free could be risky. If not then the leakage would occur.

Answer (score 34):

No, it does not. That aspect has often annoyed me since you can't just use:

```
if ((buff = realloc (buff, newsize)) == NULL)
    return;
```

in your code if you *want* to free the original on failure. Instead you have to do something like:

```
if ((newbuff = realloc (buff, newsize)) == NULL) {
    free (buff);
    return;
}
buff = newbuff;
```

Of course, I understand the rationale behind keeping the original buffer intact on failure but my use case has popped up enough that I generally code my own functions to handle that case, something like:

```
// Attempt re-allocation. If fail, free old buffer, return NULL.

static void *reallocFreeOnFail (void *oldbuff, size_t sz) {
    void *newbuff = realloc (oldbuff, sz);
    if (newbuff == NULL) free (oldbuff);
    return newbuff;
}

// Attempt re-allocation. If fail, return original buffer.
// Variable ok is set true/false based on success of re-allocation.

static void *reallocLeaveOnFail (void *oldbuff, size_t sz, int *ok) {
    void *newbuff = realloc (oldbuff, sz);
    if (newbuff == NULL) {
        *ok = 0;
        return oldbuff;
    }

    *ok = 1;
    return newbuff;
}
```

The relevant section in the C11 standard states (my italics):

> **7.20.3.4 The `realloc` function**
>
> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by the
>   `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call
>   to the `free` or `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined. If memory for the new
>   object cannot be allocated, *the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.*

Comment: The duplicate conditional jump (checking against `NULL` once before calling `free` and again inside `free`) costs more in the common case (where the pointer is not `NULL`) and only helps minimally in the rare case (where the pointer is `NULL`). I would say it's a net loss.

Comment: Actually, that's a good point, @R. The predominant case will almost certainly have a non-NULL `old` so my check doesn't really buy that much. I'll get rid of it.

Comment: You should probably also skip calling `realloc` and just call `free(old)` if `sz==0`. This is because there's some degree of disagreement on what `realloc` returning 0 can mean. Some people claim it's legal to return 0 (and not set `errno`) if the memory was successfully resized to size 0 and the implementation has `malloc(0)==NULL`, in which case the subsequent `free(old)` would be a dangerous double-free. I would write the function: `void *new=0; if (!sz || !(new=realloc(old,sz))) free(old); return new;`

Comment: Actually to give a safe "success" return on `realloc`-to-size-zero you probably need to `return malloc(1);` in this case... uhg..

Comment: @R..: Troublingly, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) says that `realloc(ptr, 0)` can fail to free `ptr` and should not be used, but [`realloc(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) says it is "equivalent to `free(ptr)`," which cannot fail because `free()` is `void` and is unable to indicate failure.

Comment: If you're on a BSD, or have libbsd avaiable (it's available in most Unix systems, including GNU/Linux distros), you can use reallocf(3).  <https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libbsd-dev/reallocf.3.en.html>

Answer (score 5):

> `realloc()` returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable and may be different from `ptr`, or `NULL` if the request fails. If `size` was equal to 0, either `NULL` or a pointer suitable to be passed to `free()` is returned. If `realloc()` fails the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

[`malloc(3)` - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Answer (score 2):

No. No change of the former buffer is done if `realloc()` failed.

> man `realloc(3)`:
>
> `realloc()` returns a pointer to the newly allocated  memory,  which  is  suitably
>       aligned  for  any kind of variable and may be different from `ptr`, or `NULL` if the
>       request fails.  If size was equal to 0, either `NULL` or a pointer suitable to  be
>       passed  to  `free()`  is  returned.  If `realloc()` fails the original block is left
>       untouched; it is not freed or moved.

Answer (score 1):

No.It won't. Realloc changes increases/decreases the dynamic memory allocated via malloc or calloc. It will return NULL in case realloc fails while increasing memory but it won't change previously allocated memory. As Realloc computes new memory allocation from the base address of previously allocated memory, it does not perform any operation on the memory