# Memory management and realloc

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm going through my program with valgrind to hunt down memory leaks. Here's one that I'm not sure what to do with.

```
==15634== 500 (224 direct, 276 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 73 of 392
==15634==    at 0x4007070: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:429)
==15634==    by 0x807D5C2: hash_set_column(HASH*, int, char const*) (Hash.cpp:243)
==15634==    by 0x807BB15: LCD::PluginDiskstats::PluginDiskstats() (PluginDiskstats.cpp:102)
==15634==    by 0x806E021: LCD::Evaluator::Evaluator() (Evaluator.cpp:27)
==15634==    by 0x8066A87: LCD::LCDControl::LCDControl() (LCDControl.h:16)
==15634==    by 0x80667F5: main (Main.cpp:8)
```

Here's the code:

```
/* add an entry to the column header table */
void hash_set_column(HASH * Hash, const int number, const char *column)
{
    if (Hash == NULL)
        return;

    Hash->nColumns++;
    Hash->Columns = (HASH_COLUMN *)realloc(Hash->Columns, Hash->nColumns * sizeof(HASH_COLUMN)); // line 243
    Hash->Columns[Hash->nColumns - 1].key = strdup(column);
    Hash->Columns[Hash->nColumns - 1].val = number;

    qsort(Hash->Columns, Hash->nColumns, sizeof(HASH_COLUMN), hash_sort_column);

}
```

Should I be doing something here in regards to memory management?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that if `realloc()` fails the function will return NULL but the original block will still be allocated.  However, you've just overwritten the pointer to that block and can't free (or use) it anymore.

Comment: Well that sort of sucks. What's an alternative to realloc?

Comment: @Scott the alternative is this: void *temp_ptr = realloc(foo, newsize);  if (temp_ptr) foo = temp_ptr;

Comment: @Scott - Write a wrapper that does this for you. It doesn't suck, it's very good - it means you won't unexpectedly lose data just because you couldn't add to the data set. It just means you have to put in a little extra effort.

Comment: @Chris: I see. I misunderstood a little. I think I've got it covered now. :)

Comment: See my other answer for what I think valgrind is really complaining about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611756/memory-management-and-realloc/1611804#1611804

Comment: @Scott, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607004/does-realloc-free-the-former-buffer-if-it-fails/1607031#1607031 for just such a wrapper.

Comment: This isn't the problem - if it was, the program would have crashed on the next line due to the NULL pointer. It's just that the pointer was never freed later.

Answer (score 2):

If realloc() fails it returns null and *the original block is not freed*. This line:

```
Hash->Columns = (HASH_COLUMN *)realloc(Hash->Columns, Hash->nColumns * sizeof(HASH_COLUMN)); // line 243
```

doesn't check the return value. So if realloc() fails null is written into Hash->Columns and the original block is leaked.

Comment: but if that were the leak he's seeing in valgrind, there'd be a null dereference and he'd crash.  my guess is there's some code he's not providing that has a leak.

Comment: hm...  sorry, to correct above comment, after thinking about this I suppose valgrind _could_ theoretically track a leak this way, even if it hasn't strictly been leaked...  was making some assumptions about valgrind that might not be accurate.

Comment: @asveikau - I think your first comment was right on the money.

Comment: @asveikau, valgrind only tracks leaks that _actually_ happened. It won't report a leak that's theoretically possible but never occured during that run of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind isn't saying that the leak is happening at the `realloc` line - it's saying that the memory that was allocated by that `realloc` line is the memory that's getting leaked, eventually.  Valgrind doesn't know where though - it just knows that you don't have a reference to that memory anymore, so it'd be impossible to `free` it.  (The OP may know this, but it's clear that many of the answerers don't!)

In short, the code you've pasted isn't causing the issue (although the issue that Michael Burr raises is definitely real, but since you're not even checking for a `NULL` returned from `realloc`...)

Somewhere in your code, there should be a `free(Hash->Columns)` which isn't there now.  Find this place - probably just before the `Hash` itself is freed - and add it.

Comment: No, it's getting freed. I made sure of it: /* free header table */
        free(Hash->Columns);

Comment: Nonetheless, that's what Valgrind is telling you.  Perhaps something is setting `Hash->Columns` to `NULL` before that point (or otherwise overwriting it), or perhaps there is alternate code path where the `free` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the issue, but it is potentially problematic. From the manpage for [`realloc()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/realloc.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion with a size not equal to 0, `realloc()` returns a pointer to the (possibly moved) allocated space. If size is 0, either a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully passed to `free()` is returned. If there is not enough available memory, `realloc()` returns a null pointer and sets errno to [ENOMEM].

What will happen is, if there isn't enough room for the expanded object, the old object *is still valid* and isn't freed, but `realloc()` returns `NULL`. So you should store the return result of `realloc()` in a separate variable, check that variable for `NULL`, and if it isn't, assign it to `Hash->Columns`.

Answer (score 1):

Aha - asveikau 's comment:

> but if that were the leak he's seeing in valgrind, there'd be a null dereference and he'd crash. my guess is there's some code he's not providing that has a leak.

has led me to another problem - the data structure you're resizeing contains pointers to strings allocated with `strdup()`.  if your `realloc()` call is making the allocation smaller, you will lose those pointers without properly freeing them first.  I believe that asveikau is correct that this is what valgrind is complaining about.

Comment: But he's not making the allocation smaller. He has `Hash->nColumns++;` right before that line, so there's no way he's making it smaller. It's always getting bigger in this example.

Comment: Good point - I missed that.  Still if, `realloc()` is returning NULL why isn't there a fault (or complaint by valgrind) on the subsequent derefernces?  Maybe nColumns is being trashed somewhere else? (I'm  reaching now)

Comment: @Michael Burr - It is truly a mystery. I suspect we may need more code to find out what's going on.

Comment: It's not the `strdup()` memory that Valgrind is saying is leaking (although I would bet a shiny dollar that there's another Valgrind message saying that too), it's the memory allocated by `realloc`.  The error is elsewhere in the code - wherever that memory is supposed to be freed.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X and FreeBSD et al. you also have the reallocf() function:

```
man 3 malloc | less -p reallocf 
... 
     The reallocf() function is identical to the realloc() function, except
 that it will free the passed pointer when the requested memory cannot be
 allocated.  This is a FreeBSD specific API designed to ease the problems
 with traditional coding styles for realloc causing memory leaks in
 libraries.
```