# Increase the maximum size of char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, size, max

I have written some code in C by taking the maximum size of char array as 100. It worked well. But when I increase the maximum size of char array to 10000 it gives me segmentation fault(as it has exceeded its limit). Can someone tell me how can I increase the maximum size and store a string of length 10000.

i.e How can I take the "char a[100]" as "char a[10000]" and execute the same code????

Comment: There is no *maximum* size, there's only the reserved size. You seem to be making a mistake. Please post a complete, minimal example, and please make sure to format all source code as source code (`{}` button over input field).

Comment: Post the code which is used to operate on `array` **a** so that it will be more clear to resolve the issue

Comment: It's unusual for a modern machine to have a problem with an array of 10k. And seg fault is usually not the right error for an allocation limit problem.  You probably have a bug that happens to be exposed by making the array bigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can allocate the array dynamically:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char *a = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
if (a == NULL)
{
 // error handling
 printf("The allocation of array a has failed");
 exit(-1);
}
```

and when you want to increase its size:

```
tmp_a = realloc(a, 10000*sizeof(char));
if ( tmp_a == NULL ) // realloc has failed
{
 // error handling
 printf("The re-allocation of array a has failed");
 free(a);
 exit(-2);
}
else //realloc was successful
{
 a = tmp_a;
}
```

Eventually, remember to free the allocated memory, when the array is not needed anymore:

```
free(a);
```

Basically `realloc(prt, size)` returns a pointer to a new memory block that has the size specified by `size` and deallocates the block pointed to by `ptr`. If it fails, the original memory block is not deallocated.
Please read [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51010-dynamic-arrays-using-malloc-and-realloc/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607004/does-realloc-free-the-former-buffer-if-it-fails) for further info.